# Куда добавлять инструкции по установке проекта?

Tags: git, github

У меня реализовано несколько сайтов в github, где мне оставить инструкцию по развертке  проектов на своем компьютере ?
Хотелось бы узнать про принятые манеры в отношении этого. Может быть в readme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каждом репозитории создай readme и там уже пропиши инструкции того, как нужно развёртывать сайт. Только не оставляй там личную инфу (логины, пароли, ключи от API и т.д.), если у тебя репозиторий публичный. Для упрощения написания readme можешь использовать online генераторы ([пример](https://dillinger.io/))

Comment: В VSC реализован реалтайм просмотр Markdown, так даже удобнее будет. [Подробнее](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Если инструкция небольшая, то прям в /readme.md, он автоматически выводится на github при открытии проекта.

Если большая, то можно в любом месте, а в readme ссылку на него.